# Apache JSTL with bug 27717 fixed

Tags: jstl

Haven't been able to find a download of Apache JSTL 1.1 with this correction....

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=27717

Can anyone point me to a download of the Apache JSTL jars with this fix included. My searches keep turning up downloads of 1.1 prior to this fix.

Thanks

Dave

Comment: In our JSTL wiki page you can find some download links, also ones pointing to 1.2 and 1.2.1. Put your mouse on top of `[jstl]` tag which you placed on the question until a black box shows up and then click therein the *info* link.

Comment: Thanks for the response.... The archive holds JSTL 1.1 jars from around 2004/2005. Bug 27717 wasn't fixed (as per the comments in the link) until late 2010. I need a much more recent build of 1.1.

Comment: In other words, 1.2 didn't work for you?

Comment: 1.2 is yet to be tried. That is the next option. 1.2 is considered an upgrade, therefore a more extensive test cycle is needed for the app. If we could get 1.1 with the bug fix applied, then we are not upgrading any app component, the test and deployment cycle is shorter.